# Computing correlation between a set of vectors and set of scalars

Tags: classification, correlation, python, matlab, intraclass-correlation

I have a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which are are associated to a scalar. In fact, it is classification problem, where the vectors are the features, and the scalar is the class. I'd like to calculate the correlation (if there is even a notion of correlation for this) between these vectors and scalars. I'd like to know this, so that I can tell how separable the data actually is.

How can correlation be calculated in this case?

Comment: Ok. I'll edit the question.

Comment: When you say you want a measure akin to correlation, could you be more specific? Closing in on a concept like correlation might narrow down the answer, while a broader question could be more easily answered. So are you searching for a single index that helps to identify if the features are somehow collectively related to the output?

Comment: Cosine similarity is a measure of similarity between two non-zero vectors of an inner product space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

Answer (score 2):

If you want a measure of linear association between the values in the vector-valued input and the scalar-valued output, then you are looking for linear regression.
A single index for this association could be R-squared or the correlation between model predictions and true values.

It also nicely fits the bivariate (scalar input, scalar output) scenario.
In that case, the R-squared is simply the squared correlation between both variables.

You lose the sense of directionality, however: you won't have a negative index, like you would with correlation.

---

As mentioned in comments, a principled choice for an approach to the problem would be logistic regression, where the dependent variables are taken to be realizations of a Bernoulli trial.

There, however, R-squared isn't a good metric.
You can look into deviance, a statistic that generalizes the R-squared to distributions other than Gaussian.

Comment: what if I want to go with a non-linear association? could I use mutual information? or what tool could I use?

Comment: It's difficult to see how any form of "linear regression" could be usefully applied to a response that is a *class,* which presumably is categorical.  Some form of logistic regression could be used, but in what sense would the result be a "correlation"?

Comment: Yes, that's actually my question. Is there a sense in which I can define some sort of "correlation"  between my features and class? The final goal is know if the data is "easily" separable, meaning that a reasonably complex classifier (a neural net) can classify it correctly.

Comment: @whuber binary dependent variables are just as possible with linear regression, even though it won't get you far towards "classification". I only mentioned it though because of the familiarity of these concepts to the OP, judging it would be easier to build from what's known.

Comment: Binary, yes: but with more than two categories, the applicability of linear regression is so implausible that I have never seen an example.

Comment: @whuber True, but it's explicitly stated that by OP the dependent variable is a single scalar. Jumping to logistic regression we ditch R² and now introduce deviance, a concept that's quite removed from correlation. That's why I chose to approach the question this way, even though people might point out that's not optimal (and I do agree, I wouldn't approach it like that, but for educational purposes it's another history).

Comment: I suspect "single scalar" means literally what it says: *a number.*  By referring to it as a "class," we may take that to mean the OP interprets the number as a *code* for a category.  As such, if it has more than two possible values it would be a mistake to treat it as numerical in a regression, which is the reason I am concerned your answer could be (and may have been) badly misinterpreted.

Comment: @whuber your interpretation is correct, and I apologize my question wasn't clear. When I say a scalar I mean a class. So a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ will be associated with one class (I use a scalar to represent a class), so vector $v_1$ is associated to let's say class -1. Other vector will be associated to other class, and so on.

Comment: In that case, Schach, this answer does not appear to respond to your intended question correctly and you might want to unaccept it.

Comment: @Schach21 so you have a binary problem (two classes), right?

Comment: It's not binary. It has more than 2 classes, but solving the binary problem is enough. I thought through my question. It's poorly formulated. I apologize. I also had another idea on how to answer what I asked; that is the KL divergence. :) but thanks for trying to help!